# vscode won't wrap html class attribute contents (class list) to multiple lines

Tags: visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, vs-code-settings

Consider this simple html with single element that has a lot of classes:

```
[...]
<body>
  <article>
    <div
      class="my-class my-12 pr-8 text-blue-800 bg-blue-500 hover:bg:blue:800 rounded-2xl abc bca cab flex justify-center items-center my-container specific-styling">
      what seriously?
    </div>
  </article>
</body>
[...]
```

Problem arises using tailwind css, obviously. Visual Studio Code does not wrap line text in html class attribute.

Default formatter does not break even when default line length is exceeded. None of wrap settings are effective, tried all.

My current project is flask+tailwind cli, without node and related npm packages. Prettier from tailwind only works with npm (?). Prettier vscode extension no longer wraps [as per this issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/10918#issuecomment-854705502), and when it did, looking at issue author screenshot, it's horrific and have no idea why they didn't wrap at customizable character length.

Is there a way to force wrap with vscode in html class attribute strictly above 120 characters?

Comment: What settings have you tried?  Did you also add the !important tag to force it to work when its being stubborn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the following settings in `settings.json`:

```json
  "[html]": {
    "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 80
  }
```